# Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT from Bookshelf.js save()

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js, node-oracledb

While testing a **Bookshelf** model insert using the **oracledb** client (versions bellow), I'm having an strange error. I've tested same code with *mysql*, *pg* and *sqlite3* clients with no problem in this operation.

My model is this:

```js
    Promotion = bookshelf.model('Promotion', {
          tableName: 'promotions'     
    })
```

And the action that triggered the error is this:

```js
Promotion.forge({image:"image","featured":false,"price":"2.33","name":"name","description":"description"}).save(null, { method:'insert' })
```

The insertion seems to be performed and commited in the database but the client returns this error:

```
(node:1098008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT. Undefined 
column(s): [promotions.id] query: select * from (select "promotions".* from "promotions" where "promotions"."image" = ?
 and "promotions"."featured" = ? and "promotions"."price" = ? and "promotions"."name" = ? and "promotions"."description
" = ? and "promotions"."id" = ?) where rownum <= ?                                                                     
    at Oracledb_Compiler.toSQL (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/knex/lib/query/compiler.js:101:13)
    at Builder.toSQL (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/knex/lib/query/builder.js:77:44)
    at /home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:30:36
    at /home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:253:24
    at tryCatcher (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/user/src/tests/app/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
(node:1098008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Using this versions:

- **bookshelf** 1.1.0 (also tested 1.0.1 with same error)
- **knex** 0.20.9 (also 0.20.8)
- **oracledb** 4.2.0

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: It happens when one of the bindings values is `undefined`

Comment: Could be an issue with the feature that automatically refreshes the model after a save, although I don't understand why it would behave differently only with OracleDB. What happens if you just call `.save()` without any arguments?

Comment: Yes, I think this issue is because of the feature to return the saved object after a successfull save, because the save (insert) is performed but the fetch (select) to return the object is what triggers the error. If I use save() without any argument, the call succeds, but it performs an UPDATE in the DB, not an insert.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are reproducing the same bug, so I went ahead and created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312488/updating-a-morph-one-associated-model-and-receiving-unhandled-rejection-error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. after saving the new instance to the database, the select statement fails. fixed it like this:

```js
 await new BusinessOwnerSpecialty(newSpecialty)
        .save(null,{autoRefresh:false})
```

The ***{autoRefresh:false}*** option fixed the issue.
source : https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-save