# Updating a Morph-One Associated model and receiving "Unhandled rejection Error"

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

### Code

#### Preferred way

```
this.related('title').save({value: input});
```

But as this line is cut and pasted from a middle of some abstract class, below is a more decoupled way of directly reproducing the same error message.

#### Alternative Implementation

```
let title = await book.related('title');
title.set({value: inputs.title});
title.save().then( (model) => {} );
```

### Error message

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT. Undefined column(s): [titles.titleable_id] query: select distinct `titles`.* from `titles` where `titles`.`id` = ? and `titles`.`titleable_id` = ? and `titles`.`titleable_type` = ? limit ?
    at QueryCompiler_MySQL.toSQL (/Users/captainhusaynpinguin/Documents/sails/ilog/node_modules/knex/lib/query/compiler.js:101:13)
    at Builder.toSQL (/Users/captainhusaynpinguin/Documents/sails/ilog/node_modules/knex/lib/query/builder.js:77:44)
    at /Users/captainhusaynpinguin/Documents/sails/ilog/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:31:36
    at /Users/captainhusaynpinguin/Documents/sails/ilog/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:260:24
```

Notice: though the above error is printed in the terminal, because of JavaScript's way of performing nested functions, the program actually updates the row in the database and continues with rendering the response view. However this error can cause breaking the program in the middle (displaying a 500 view) when the same functionality is in combination with `await` ...

### Background

Bookshelf.js is hooked to Sails-JS via a custom hook:

#### model: Title

```
let Post = require('../Post')

var Title = sails.hooks.orm.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'titles',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    titleable() {
        return this.morphTo('titleable', 'Post')
    }
});

module.exports = sails.hooks.orm.bookshelf.model('Title', Title);
```

#### model: Post

```
let Post = sails.hooks.orm.bookshelf.Model.extend(
    tableName: 'posts',
    title() {
         return this.morphOne('Title', 'titleable', ['titleable_type', 'titleable_id'])
    }
);

module.exports = Post;
```

- MacOS Sierra
- mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for osx10.12 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
- node v12.13.1
- Sails v1.2.4
- bookshelf@1.1.1
- knex@0.21.0

### Other unanswered questions appearing to address similar issue/bug

[Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT from Bookshelf.js save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234474/error-undefined-bindings-detected-when-compiling-select-from-bookshelf-js-sav)

### Possible explanation

As the api documentation notices, the `save()` method performs an automatic retrieve of the model, by which time I think **Bookshelf** fails to pass the initial details (`titleable_type` and `titleable_id`) over to **knex**.

PS. I'm just beginning to use JS for backend, so, apologies in advance if the error is caused by some beginner mistakes/misunderstandings of basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why the aforementioned approach results in the said error, but for the time being below implementation does the job without throwing any error:

```
post.load('title').then(function(model) {
    model.related('title').save({value: input});
    return model;
});
```

Feel free to edit this work-around & add more details/explanations; or even better, answer the question!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. And you're right the `save()` method does perform an automatic retrieve of the model. not sure why it is failing though.
In my case, I fixed it by turning off the auto retrieval of the model after creation. I added `{autoRefresh:false}` to the parameters of the `save()` function.

Like this:

```
await new BusinessOwnerSpecialty(newSpecialty)
        .save(null,{autoRefresh:false})
        .then(()=>{
            /* the rest of the code */
            });
        })
```

This way the auto retrieval of the newly created/updated model was turned off, and my problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I was using this method in an open-source CMS package I'm gonna release in a while, you're welcomed to feedback if you think we should go around it any other way: https://vitualizersgit.xyz/iatelier/sails/iatelier/-/blob/master/api/models/Book.js